# Input BASH variable inside PHP script file

Tags: php, bash

I have bash script */media/mes_test/my_script.bash*:

```
#!/bin/bash
path1="/media/mes_test/2.txt"
link=`/usr/bin/php << EOF
<?php
include('/media/mes_test/index.php');
?>
EOF`
echo "$link"
```

file (function only to illustrate) */media/mes_test/index.php*:

```
<?php
echo "$path1";
?>
```

Why wnen i run script:

```
$ bash /media/mes_test/my_script.bash
```

As a result I see a blank line.
But should be displayed:

```
/media/mes_test/2.txt
```

**Why command `echo "$path1";`  does not work?**

Comment: You're trying to set a variable in bash and retrieving it from php. That won't work. You could echo the variable within the bash call as an argument to the php script and access it from there. But I honestly can't think of a single reasonable application of this.

Comment: export the bash variable in your bash script, then use [getenv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) to retrieve it in your PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thenx for Mark Baker! 
ANSWER:

*/media/mes_test/my_script.bash:*

```
#!/bin/bash
export path1="/media/mes_test/2.txt"
link=`/usr/bin/php << EOF
<?php
include('/media/mes_test/index.php');
?>
EOF`
echo "$link"
```

*/media/mes_test/index.php:*

```
<?php 
echo getenv("path1");
?>
```

result on the screen:

```
/media/mes_test/2.txt
```

P.S. Thank Joel GEO for attention to my question.

I write a script that will take messages from the folder where it goes over 100 per second.
bash script for php said letter location ->
php extracts from the letter of the required information and said that everything is complete for bash script ->
bash script erases the file and repeat the action with the next letter until the folder will not be empty